# Can't insert FormData in mysql using Php and jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I am trying to insert data in mysql table using Jquery ajax. My jquery codes is as follows.

```
$("#join-form-submit").on("click", function(){
 if($("#join-fullname").val() && $("#join-username").val() && $("#join-email").val() && $("#join-phone").val() && $("#join-location").val()){

   var formData = new FormData();

   var fullname = $("#join-fullname").val();
   formData.append('fullname', fullname);

   var username = $("#join-username").val();
   formData.append('username', username);

   var email = $("#join-email").val();
   formData.append('email', email);

   var phone = $("#join-phone").val();
   formData.append('phone', phone);

   var location = $("#join-location").val();
   formData.append('location', location);

   $.ajax({
       url : 'new_sales.php',
       type : 'POST',
       data : formData,
       contentType : false,
       processData : false,
       success : function(data){
           alert("Success");
           console.log(fullname);
           console.log(username);
           console.log(email);
           console.log(phone);
           console.log(location);
       }
   });

 } else {
   $(".join-form-error").slideDown().delay(3000).slideUp();
 }
 });
```

This part is working fine and I am getting my input data in console.log after clicking the button but the data is not inserted in mysql server.

the code at new_sales.php is as follows

```
 <?php

  $fullname = $_POST["fullname"];

  $user_name = $_POST["username"];

  $email = $_POST["email"];

  $phone = $_POST["phone"];

  $location = $_POST["location"];

  $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "zzz", "xxxx", "wedoinst_main");

 $sql = "INSERT INTO new_sales (fullname, user_name, email, phone, location) VALUES ('$fullname', '$user_name', '$email', '$phone', '$location')";


 ?>
```

Please point out the mistake I am doing here.

Thanks

Comment: In this code you are not executing the sql. I would use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection attacks instead of placing the vars inside the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the query.

```
$conn->query($sql);
```

Also you need to use prepared statements to prevent sql injection

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO new_sales (fullname, user_name, email, phone, location) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

$result = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$result->bind_param('sssss',$fullname, 
$user_name,$email, $phone, $location); 
echo $result->execute() === true ?  'success' : 'query failed '. $conn->error;
```

Comment: I understand the use of prepared statement but I missed the `$conn->query($sql)` part. Thank you for your help.

Comment: pleasure. happy to help out